# Matrix column independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix $A \in R^{(m \times n)}$ with $m \leq n$. All rows in the matrix are linearly independent. Does it hold that I can select **any** $m$ columns from $A$ and they will also be linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take

$$
A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0&\cdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 &0& 0& 0&\cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 &0& 0& 0&\cdots \end{array} \right)
$$

Then "all rows in the matrix are linearly independent" and it you can't " select any $3$ columns from $A$ and they will also be linearly independent".

Comment: Thanks, not a very smart question.

Comment: I reformulated my question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269144/invertability-of-submatrix